# Conversion on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, conversion-to-judaism

Can a person who is converting can he do the conversion on Shabbos? Is there problems of tevillah ( is this considered a tevillah shel Mitzvah) and Circumsion( are geirim like 8 day old baby)?

Comment: Can the court convene?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One cannot convert on *shabbat*.

The circumcision may not be performed on *shabbat* - see [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch Yalkut Yosef 331:41](https://moreshet-maran.com/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8-%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%A7%D7%99-%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94/%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F-%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%90-%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA/).

The immersion may also not be performed on *shabbat*, as it requires the presence of a court - see [Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah 268:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.268.4?lang=bi).

Comment: Though if you did it anyway, it does take effect

Comment: @DoubleAA meaning if you did everything? Bris milah and tevillah?